# "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied" error in Release Management client

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have been working on Release Management client for last few months. I tried to configure "agentless" deployment using chef.

I configured all the attributes that were mentioned in the below documentation.

Reference can be found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/07/08/how-to-trigger-deployments-to-chef-managed-environments-from-release-management-2013-with-update-3-rc/) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn833189%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).

After creating the release template, I tried to deploy it on the chef host, but it throws an exception as

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.CommonConfiguration.Helpers.ProcessHelper.ExecuteProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo, String argumentsWithStarsForPassword, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Boolean waitForExit)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.CommonConfiguration.Helpers.ProcessHelper.RunProcess(String fileName, String arguments, String workingDirectory, Boolean waitForExit)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.MonitorServices.Chef.OnPrem.KnifeInvoker.Invoke(String arguments, String existingLogs)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.MonitorServices.Chef.OnPrem.ChefCommands.SetAttribute(ChefDeploymentInfo deploymentInfo)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.MonitorServices.Chef.OnPrem.ChefOnPremDeploymentActions.InvokePipeline(ChefDeploymentInfo deploymentInfo)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.MonitorServices.Chef.OnPrem.ChefOnPremDeploymentActions.TriggerDeployment(DscComponent dscComponentParameters, String nodeName, String isUnixNode, String userName, String password, String componentName, String attributeName, String knifeInstallationPath, String chefRepoPath)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.DeploymentAgent.Services.Deployer.Dsc.DscComponentInstaller.InvokeMethodByReflection(String methodArguments)
```

Can anyone please help me to find out what I missed and what needs to be configured?

I used Unix based credentials, I checked one step forward under Server Manager -> All Servers -> Events page. The error is mentioned below

```
Timestamp: 8/5/2016 1:36:46 PM
Message: Access is denied: \r\n\r\n   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.CommonConfiguration.Helpers.ProcessHelper.ExecuteProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo, String argumentsWithStarsForPassword, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Boolean waitForExit)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.CommonConfiguration.Helpers.ProcessHelper.RunProcess(String fileName, String arguments, String workingDirectory, Boolean waitForExit)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.MonitorServices.Chef.OnPrem.KnifeInvoker.Invoke(String arguments, String existingLogs)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.MonitorServices.Chef.OnPrem.ChefCommands.SetAttribute(ChefDeploymentInfo deploymentInfo)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.MonitorServices.Chef.OnPrem.ChefOnPremDeploymentActions.InvokePipeline(ChefDeploymentInfo deploymentInfo)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.MonitorServices.Chef.OnPrem.ChefOnPremDeploymentActions.TriggerDeployment(DscComponent dscComponentParameters, String nodeName, String isUnixNode, String userName, String password, String componentName, String attributeName, String knifeInstallationPath, String chefRepoPath)
Category: General
Priority: -1
EventId: 0
Severity: Error
Title:
Machine: AMAZONA-U157LUU
Application Domain: ReleaseManagementMonitor.exe
Process Id: 1516
Process Name: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Release Management\bin\ReleaseManagementMonitor.exe
Win32 Thread Id: 4956
Thread Name: 
Extended Properties:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NodeName:** Name of the Chef Node where you want to deploy the application. The parameter passed should match the name of the Server linked in RM Standard environment.

```
Note : Make sure your node name match with the same in node input field.
```

**IsUnixNode:** Specify type of the machine. In case of UNIX based machines this parameter is set to true.
Username/Password: Credentials to connect to the node. This should be a user (sudo privileges) with ssh permission for UNIX based systems and an user with winrm permission(or local admin) for WINDOWS based systems
Component Name: Name of the component to be deployed.

```
Note: Select your appropriate component in your project.
```

**Attribute Name:** Name of the Chef node attribute which is used by cookbook(s) to get application package as explained earlier. Nested attributes are supported. The format of this name is:  [‘AttributeLevel1’][‘AttributeLevel2’]…

```
Note: Verify you chef attribute name and attribute input field name. ex: ['test']
```

**KnifeInstallationPath:** Absolute path to knife.bat file on Release Management Server

```
Note:upto your knife.rb file location. ex:C:\opscode\chefdk\bin\knife.bat
```

**ChefRepoPath:** Chef repo directory path on RM server.

```
Note: upto knife.rb located folder. Ex :C:\Users\Administrator.TFS\.chef
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates a "Access is denied" issue. You need to check whether you have filled the correct Configuration variables especially Username/Password in the action “Deploy Using Chef”.

> **Username/Password**: Credentials to connect to the node. This should be
>   a user (sudo privileges) with ssh permission for UNIX based systems
>   and an user with winrm permission(or local admin) for WINDOWS based
>   systems

Comment: I checked the access from TFS server to the node. knife command works fine from the TFS on-premise server but the chef deploy from TFS release management client fails with 'Access Denied' at the Deploy state. I have placed the artifact in a Network shared store (Builds Externall UNC path) and I could access the artifact from the TFS server. Not sure what is failing. Any suggestions to resolve this would greatly help.

Reference images
https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/ks-tfs/component.png ,
https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/ks-tfs/releasestate.png

Comment: Are you able to open your RM Server URL in browser? Which account did you use to configure your RM server?